# Modal window with editable information with bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a project where the HTML table rows have been created with information of Name, Details, Phone, Email etc. All this information is stored in a database.

Now, I want obtain a modal box, when I click on the table row and obtain information which is there on the row in a neat and tidy form. As you can see from the code, I have already put it an alert box. However, instead of this, I would like to get the same information in a modal box using Jquery and bootstrap.

For this please find the existing codes that are in place. I have not put any codes for the modal part. This is because, I am not sure how to get the table row as a modal button.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))

    $uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

    require_once('connect.php');

    $ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid AND ACTIVE_INACTIVE=1 ORDER BY Name";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<form action="http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                    </form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Add Contact" onclick="window.location.href='http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/comp_contact_index.php'" />
</form>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Motoko</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

        .table-hover tbody tr:hover td
        {
            background-color: #A9A9A9;
            color: white;         
        }
        body

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('table tbody tr').click(function (){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>




<body> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
        <table class="table table-hover">

            <tr>
                <th><strong>Contact Category</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Details</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Phone</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            ?>
            <tr>                    
                <td class= "r-Type"><?php echo $r['Contact_type']; ?></td> 
                <td class= "r-Name"><?php echo $r['Name']; ?></td> 
                <td class="r-Details"><?php 

                if ($r['Contact_type'] == 'Individual')
                {
                echo $r['Title']. ', '.$r['Company']; 
                }

                elseif ($r['Contact_type'] == 'Team')
                {
                echo $r['Company']; 
                }

                elseif ($r['Contact_type'] == 'Company')
                {
                echo ''; 
                }


                ?> </td>
                <td class="r-Phone"><?php echo $r['Phone']; ?></td> 
                <td class="r-Email"><?php echo $r['Email']; ?></td> 
                <td class="r-Address"><?php echo $r['Address']; ?></td> 
                <td class="r-Update"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
                <td class="r-Delete"><a href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']?>'>Delete</a></td>

            </tr>

            <?php } ?>
            </table>            
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Jquery used

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('table tbody tr').click(function (){
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on your '.click()' event, you can open a `bootdtrap` modal. Here's a demo modal that might help you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h2>Click the button to get row information</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal">Get Information</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="infoModal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 14%">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Row Information</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Values: </label>
            <input id="val1" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Now this modal has an input box which has `id`. So first you set its value with what you get in your alert by doing: `$('#val1').val($(this).text());`.

Once the value is set, you need to open the `modal`.

For opening the modal, inside your `.click()` function, after the value setting, do `$('#infoModal').modal('show');`. This will open the modal with your row values in the input box.

Hope this helps. If it doesn't it'll definitely help you along achieving what you want.

Comment: Hi, I tried this. This is however, giving a modal button separately.
What I need is to make the table row as a button, which when clicked would open a modal box with the text information on the row. It would be great if you could help with this. Thanks

Comment: Just insert the `button` tag into your row. SImple.